# Is there data transfer on wire while pinging a local ip?

Tags: linux, ping, loopback

Assuming my local ip is 1.1.1.2, when I run ping 1.1.1.2

1. The kernel drives the network device to transmit/receive data on wire
2. The kernel fakes the replies since it knows I am pinging self

What does kernel do, 1 or 2?
If the answer is 2, how can I achieve 1?

BR, Ruochen

Answer (score 1):

3. It will not transmit it on the wire, and the replies are not fake. They are just not sent on the wire. The entire IP stack is normally in work, except the queue to hardware.